# I was wondering if there is a way to use multirow package along with siunitx (more details in the description)?

Tags: latex

I'm struggling in LaTeX trying to use the command `S[table-format = 3.0]` on a column defined by multirow commands, here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
        S[table-format = 3.0]S[table-format = 2.0] |
        S[table-format = 1.2] S[table-format = 1.2] S[table-format = 4.0] S[table-format = 1.2] S[table-format = 4]
    }
        \toprule
        {a} & {b} & {c} & {d} & {e} & {f} & {g}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}*{50}
        & 10 & 0.37 & 0.45 & 552 & 0.59 & 52 \\
        & 25 & 0.43 & 0.44 & 3076 & 0.56 & 245 \\
        & 50 & 0.45 & 0.43 & 637 & 0.64 & 715 \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}*{100}
        & 10 & 0.34 & 0.50 & 1138 & 2.76 & 110 \\
        & 25 & 0.40 & 0.48 & 1224 & 0.94 & 326 \\
        & 50 & 0.38 & 0.49 & 443 & 0.44 & 1056 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{
        Results 
    }
    \label{tab:experiments}
\end{table}
```

When I try to compile this code, the compiler gives me back an error.
However if you substitute `S[table-format = 3.0]` with `c` the code works, but the numbers in that column are not aligned as I wish.
Can someone give me further explanations or even a solution to align with `S[…]` the numbers passed to `\multirow{...}`?

Comment: Almost certainly better to ask this kind of question at https://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of a code fragment

Comment: Why do you use 'S' for the first column as it does not have any decimal dot... And you must be very careful when using a a siunitx column in a multirow https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368679/siunitx-incompatible-with-multirow